# Adjective for someone who lives life to the fullest or lives in the present?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an adjective describing someone who lives life to the fullest or lives in the present? I would also prefer one-worded answers or hyphenated ones!

Sample Sentence: She's such a [word] person, I really admire how she lives her life to the fullest.

Comment: Dynamic? In-the-moment? Lively?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word **effervescent** (adjective) which can be used refer to a energetic, positive and active person.